# My sound in Ubuntu keeps randomly dying, i can't find anyway to resolve it other than restarting, but i'd like to fix it permanently

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have tried 10+ fixes that people have suggested and scoured forums, I've even switched distros to Ubuntu to see if it works.

Does anyone know where the hell to begin? I have a PRIME A320M-K board. I'm connected to my TV with a standard HDMI cord, I've tried numerous fixes and attempted solutions. Everything is up to date!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please edit your question and add some more details like what version of Ubuntu you are running and what other fixes you have tried so that we are not suggesting to you to try the things that you have already.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, if you run pulseaudio -k that will kill and restart the audio server without having to restart your computer. No idea on what is causing it, but at least this works good enough.